# Return items in random order from a loop

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a windows command line to return items from a list in random order?

```
         FOR %%g in (dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4) DO (
         //do something with any dir returned in random order
         )
```

Thanks

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to process them sequentially?

Comment: Yes. These directories are further processed with few commands. And I dont want my tests to do the same thing all the time. I should try to get different dir + command combination each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code which may help you. It generates a random number between 0 and 2 (inclusive) and then uses that to pick a directory to work on:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /A R=%random%%% 3

set /A Counter=0
FOR %%g in (dir1 dir2 dir3 dir4) DO (
    if !Counter!==%R% echo %%g
    set /A Counter+=1
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have considered using %random%. Only problem being that I have keep track of what directories are already processed. But looks like there is not easy way to do this.

Comment: You could use %random% to randomize the order of the list, before you enter the processing loop....